# Coworker insulted me through text after asked about a task he failed to complete for me

Tags: unprofessional-behavior, relationships, conflict, colleagues

What should I do in this situation. I'm not sure what triggered him to do this, but it boils down to:
He is responsible for maintaining the computer I work on among many other things. For 2 weeks he has failed to get my machine back to me. He wiped it clean without asking if I needed to save anything and I lost some work assets, along with about 10 hours of work in progress. I texted him about this and he straight up personally insulted my character.

Comment: Can you elaborate on _what_ you texted? There seem to be some assumptions about your text being unprofessional, but that doesn't seem to be coming from your current question.

Comment: we need to more information to answer this. is text your usual avenue, are the phones u communicate via work phones, why are you only contacting him now, how big is your company, on and on

Comment: I texted him "I mean I don't have my own machine and cube for 2 weeks, I feel like that a pretty big inconvenience. As well as losing about 10 hours of work on a ticket because you neglected to let me save anything or even ask me before wiping my machine"

Comment: This coworker does not have a primary responsibility for updating these machines, but it's his unofficial duty to maintain them. His primary job is the same as mine. It's indirectly his fault that my machine was disabled in the first place, as the permissions were incorrectly configured when he set it up. We have no professional channels provided to contact each other, so text is usual.

Comment: Company is a large (but mismanaged) corporation, and we have very few resources to really do anything so we've had to resort to things like this, where other engineers have unofficial responsibilities

Answer (score 6):

It's a professional /workplace issue. You shouldn't have contacted him through text in the first place. Bring this up to your supervisor/manager ASAP and let him/her deal with it.